# Parse deleteInBackground stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.hitText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as! String

    cell.hitText.numberOfLines = 0

    let score = object.valueForKey("count") as! Int

    cell.count.text = "\(score)"

    var dateUpdated = object.createdAt as NSDate

    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    cell.time.text = (NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String) as String

    let replycnt = object.objectForKey("replies") as! Int

    if cell.count.text! == "\(-10)"

    {

    object.deleteInBackground()

    }


    return cell

}
```

My code worked wonderfully but as of last night it stopped working. It does not delete anything now and I changed nothing. Is there an alternative?

Edits.

The way this works is the following. As the cell.count.text equals -10, once items are refreshed, the object should be deleted. This holds true for all instances when count will be -10, as in there are -10 votes.

I attempted to change it to both

```
deleteEventually()  
delete()
```

however those don't work either. This seems to be an anomaly for as I have mentioned, this block of code worked perfectly previously.

**EDIT**

It seems as though the reason for the sporadic changes, is due in part to the parse server speed.

Comment: On SO, this is called a "why doesn't my code work" question.  There's a closure category specifically for this.  To get the help you want, please edit the question and explain what debugging steps you've taken, and what the results were.  Do you have a hypothesis about what's going wrong, can you test it?  That it worked last night, is a very salient fact, but that's not the end of thought.  It's not working now, confront it that way.

Comment: I'll edit my question but I doubt I'll get some help. I do not have a hypothesis, since as I stated it worked last night. I rewrote all code however I periodically save instances of previous code. I went back and checked and those aren't working either in regard to this. I'll see what I can do to make the question more approachable to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more surprised that the code once worked than I am surprised it doesn't work now.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` runs each time a row becomes visible in the table view.  That is no place to check a deletion condition much less perform the deletion.  Imagine the user scrolling back and forth... you'll be checking that delete condition for every object over and over, possibly deleting it just as you're configuring a view to display it.

The time you *should* check the condition is outside of this method, whenever the `object.valueForKey("count")` changes.  When you detect the deletion condition, delete the object and call loadObjects, which fetch the data again (now absent the deleted object) and reload the table...

That will look something like this:

```
// an object's "count" property just changed, if it is <= -10 delete it
object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        self.loadObjects();
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}

// also remove the cell.count.text condition and the delete from the posted code
```

Comment: This is the weirdest damn thing. I took a gif of the previous code suddenly working again, http://gyazo.com/07f71337d8a4ff16cafe6119e01da41d I do have a problem with greater than not working, but your code works as well. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: I think what you're seeing with your code could be a race condition between the user causing the delete condition and initiating the refresh.  You block-free delete method doesn't let you know when the delete completes (and therefore when a refresh will have the desired effect).  If that's true, then you'll continue to see intermittent behavior change depending on network conditions and load conditions at parse. Even if that's not the case, hopefully you see my point about why it is bad design to update the model supporting the table in the method that presents the current state of that model.

Comment: I surely do, thanks for the help. My latest challenge now is going to be figuring out why >= and <= aren't having the desired results.

Comment: Do you mean `cell.count.text! >= "\(-10)"` ?? That's a string comparison.  What you should do is compare with the int value you put in `score`.  As an aside, maybe clean up your naming.  If the column name is count, then have the variable names `countInt` and/or `countString`, have the label called `countLabel`.  Or change the column name to score and change those variable names accordingly.   This will save you some headache later.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with danh, tableViews actually "reuse" cells which can lead to unpredictable behavior so its best to keep as much logic outside the table data source functions as possible.